# AngularJS and Spring MVC-webflow

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-webflow

Can i itegrade Spring webflow with AngularJS 1?
The internet seem to sugget that this is not possible
if so, how do i control the flow with Angular? ngRoute?

Trying to build a website based on AngularJS1 and Spring MVC

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible to build a web application using angular js and spring MVC. You can refer

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/

Comment: The question is about Spring Webflow specifically.